# Where is self.emit emitted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, irc

I'm using IRC npm and my bot hasn't been connecting to an IRC server and I wasn't receiving any errors. So I went into the source code to find out what was happening. 
[image]

Apparently the function was ran. Where is it being emitted?

And I found this:

```
 util.log('Connection got "close" event');
```

Where is it logged to?

Comment: It's logged to `stdout`, which means it should display in the window running node.

Comment: Yeah I see other stuff now, I didn't enable debugging. Thanks.                                          if ( self.opt.debug )